Animation issue with SplitNavigationView
I'd like to use a NavigationSplitView for the iPad version of my app, but I experience some animation issues, when in compact mode on an iPad (split view or slide over) and when I'm running the app on an iPhone:

Every now and then the title is briefly shown "large" when navigating to the sub view, although it's supposed to be shown "inline". The let's the remaining content bump up after a split second. Comment out the .navigationBarBackButtonHidden() in the example below if you want to try it out repeatedly.

The back button is also shown briefly before actually hiding - moreover the sub view buttons in the navigation bar are not show from the very beginning but at the same time the back button actually hides.


Why is that? Is there any workaround known? I experienced this issue with iOS 15 in the simulator and on real devices running iOS 17.5 as well.
Here's the copy & paste example code to reproduce the issue:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView(
            sidebar: {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink("Leave", destination: {
                        Text("go back")
                            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                            .navigationTitle(Text("Test"))
                            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
                            .toolbar {
                                ToolbarItemGroup(placement:  .topBarTrailing) {
                                    HStack {
                                        Button("A", action: {})
                                        Button("B", action: {})
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    })
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItemGroup(placement:  .topBarTrailing) {
                        HStack {
                            Button("C", action: {})
                            Button("D", action: {})
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            detail: {
                Text("empty")
            }
        )
    }
}



#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


I just found a workaround that works for me: based on the horizontalSizeClass I replace the NavigationSplitView with a NavigationStack which does not have those issues. Seems like a OS bug for me. But I'd still be interested in your ideas/other workarounds or confirmation regarding my suspicion.
